# How to prevent current tab URL to load some requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to prevent some requests to be made from certain URLs. Example:

I'm at www.url.com/news/currentNews.html and I want to block some requests being made from this URL structure (i.e. www.url.com/*/*), but I don't want to block any request being made from www.url.com (the main page).

From inside background.js we can use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`, but it intercepts all requests regardless of the current URL, which doesn't work for me.

I know we can get current tab URL from background.js using `chrome.tabs.query`, however, since this is an async method, I couldn't make it work the way I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Intercept all requests, check whether it matches your criteria. If it does, block it, otherwise allow it through.

Comment: Oh, I see, your criteria is dependent on the current URL, which can't be retrieved synchronously.

Comment: This is similar to the problem of doing asynchronous validation of form fields. You have to block the normal execution of requests, and then emulate the original request in the callback function of the `chrome.tabs.query()` function if it meets the allowable criteria.

Comment: Which could be tricky, since you have to ensure that the original request's event listeners get invoked for the replacement request.

Comment: There should be at least one answer for this topic. The solution is quite trivial: maintain a global map of tabId -> url in your background script which you populate in chrome.tabs.onUpdated, for example.

Comment: @Barmar, any code in mind? :)

Comment: @wOxxOm, what exactly I should do with this map? AFAIK to get current tab id from background.js I have to call an async method, which doesn't work for me. Or maybe I'm not seeing your point.

Comment: A map is `var map = {}` or `var map = new Map()` where the key is tabId and the value is URL. It's already inside your background script, no need for async stuff. You can look for an existing answer, but I think it's rather self-explanatory.

Comment: @Fulalas No code in mind, I don't know how you would create this replacement request that would satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think you don't understand the problem. When deciding whether to allow the web request to proceed, you need to know the URL *now*, but it's not yet in the map, because you can only get the URL using an asynchronous call.

Comment: I do understand and this is really trivial: tabs.onUpdated triggers on tab creation or navigation where you update the map variable with the tab URL, and only after that the sub-requests are performed which you intercept in webRequest.onBeforeRequest with the URL already in the map. I won't be following this thread anymore, I'm too lazy.